# Pass React Element to Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an element whose id I'm passing to a library, but it takes time to perform the operations on the passed element. It currently looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(build("#el")).then(() => {
    ...
    })
  }, [])

  // build() is the function imported from an external library
  // which creates some sort of visualisation of element `el`
  return(
    <>
      <Component1 />
      <div id="el" />
      <Component />
    </>
  )
```

So I wanted to create a loader, that would run till the function is running, like so:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(build("#el")).then(() => {
    ...
    }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [])

  if(loading) return <div>Loading...</div>

   return(
    <>
      <Component1 />
      <div id="el" />
      <Component />
    </>
  )
```

But the problem with this is that the external library is not able to find the element "el" because it doesn't exist in the DOM till the point loading is false. It would work if I create the element directly in index.html but then, I would not be able to position this element.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `build` is the function imported from the external library, it creates some visualisation on the element `el`.

Comment: I do want the `loading` state to run until the `build()` is completed; The problem is that then it doesn't find `el` in the DOM. I somehow want it to pre-exist in the DOM.

Comment: when loading=true,#el not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an early return you could conditionally render the loader *in addition to* the empty `#el` div.

```
return(
  <>
    ... possibly other content

    {loading && <div>Loading...</div>)

    ... possibly other content

    {!loading && <Component1 />}

    <div id="el"></div>

    {!loading && <Component />}

    ... possibly other content
  </>
)
```

The gist is that you want the `#el` div rendered regardless of the `loading` state. The rest of the UI of this component can revolve around being conditionally rendered by the `loading` state if they need to be.

Comment: This works in this case but my React component returns multiple elements and the element `el` has to be positioned within it. So rendering it below everything else would not be the right thing to do, which is why I was returing it early. I just edited my example to show it what I mean.

Comment: could you use `display: none;` on `#el` in order to hide it but still be within the DOM for the library to gain access to it?

Comment: @ShreySachdeva This pattern doesn't effect ***where*** you render the `<div id="el"></div>` within this component, it can be rendered wherever you were rendering it previously. Would it help if I placed some "...." in there to indicate there is other content?